# Send 404 using request dispatcher JSP

Tags: java, jsp, aem

I am implementing a custom 404 handler in JSP - AEM, CQ.
The file lives in apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp

I am intercepting the request for Not Found and forwarding using RequestDispatcher class.

```
<%@taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling"%>
<sling:defineObjects />
<%
    // setting response code as 404
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
response.setStatus(404);
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
        try {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error-page.html");

            rd.forward(request, response);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error-page.html");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }

%>
```

The above code gets the content of error-page.html keeping the URL same, but the response code sent back is not 404. It is 200 instead.

How can I return a 404?

Comment: if you are forwarding to an error page (and the error page exists), you are bound to get a 200, right?

Comment: I think so too, I tried to include(req, res) but still 200.

Comment: what is the point of sending 404 error code as you have already intercepted it and sent a genetic 404 error page. You could just log the error message and continue ? I fail to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: This is custom page that I am trying to send, and it will based on the users location.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but as an aside — error handling can be tricky to nail in Sling/AEM, as sometimes the page your including can overwrite the status code that you've set. Where it does this is non-obvious (if you're extending the default `Page` supertype), as it's knitted into the `libs` directory.  I'd suggest using something like the [ACS Commons Error Page Handler plugin](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/errorpagehandler.html) to take the pain out of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `#include` rather than `#forward` will allow you to return a 404:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(path);
dispatcher.include(request,response);
```

I would suggest creating a Java Servlet rather than using JSP:

```
@SlingServlet(metatype = true, resourceTypes = {"/apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler"}, extensions = {"404"})
public class ErrorServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("myPath");
        dispatcher.include(request,response);
    }
}
```

Are you checking for the status code in AEM directly or are you checking after Apache and Dispatcher?

Comment: I am checking at both places, but this strategy works on both AEM publish and dispatcher. Servlet seemed a cleaner approach. Thanks!

Comment: If you were only checking post Dispatcher I would want to see your result pre Dispatcher because we don't know how your Apache web server is configured.